# How to modify the custom module URL?

Tags: custom, url-rewrite, magento2.2.7, paths

I have created custom module i.e `/stores/index/display`.

But I want to modify the `/stores`, How can I do that?

Comment: What url you should use for your module?

Comment: mention what url you want to need ?

Comment: @Parshuram you can create your custom controller with custom routes

Comment: my URL is  locate/stores/index/display

Comment: but just modify the locate/stores how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the controller name inside Controller >> Index >> Display.php to Index.php and change the layout also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your route just `/stores` or what ever unique name.
For that you have to create folder with name `Index` & Action name `Index`

For example in your case your structure will be:

[image]

CustomRequestPosts is my module name, so you just have to change your file name Display.php to Index.php
Let me know is still have any confusion on routes.

Comment: @parshuram IS this working for you ? or you want something else ?

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @Parshuram Update your question with all your module files